# Is it possible to save the data from Pre-Chat from to Live Agent Transcript record?

Tags: liveagent, pre-chat, chat

I want to save the data filled up by the customer in pre-chat form to Live agent transcript record. But I don't see any documented function to do this. Is this possible ? For deployment API, this type of function exists and it is documented in the dev guide but nothing for pre-chat API. 
Any insight on this is very helpful

Comment: Can you post your code of pre-chat form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do this using prechat.save

```
<input type='text' name='liveagent.prechat:RequestType' />

<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.save:RequestType" value="Request_Type__c" />
```

where Request_Type__c is custom field on Live Chat transcript object.
This is not documented in the developer guide but discussed below,
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000159850&language=en_US&type=1